# Fluid Simulation is still low quality even with resolution of 250

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make my fluid look realistic but it isn't smooth even with the quality set to 250.

I have uploaded a video of it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E54ObJrXHiM

Is there any settings I should change?

I changed the viscosity to these settings:
Base: 10 | Exponent: 3 | Domain size is also: 3m

Smoothing: 2 | Subdivisions: 2

Simulation Speed: 0.08

Here is a close up:

[image]
http://s24.postimg.org/vvq2ryhtx/fluid.png

Comment: Resolution is relative to the size of the domain (see related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14386/599). With a large domain, you may have to increase the resolution a little more. As for the shading, [make sure smooth shading is enabled](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36274/599).

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, a resolution of 250 isn't that much. Everything will look crappy at that resolution. And as gandalf3 said, make sure your domain isn't unnecessarily large.

Setting subdivisions to 2 won't really improve your simulation in this case. Change it back to 0 (or 1, because of blender logic it is the same) and save some baking time.

For extra smoothing, use the smooth modifier. However, it may reveal holes in the fluid mesh, so make sure you check what's going on before you render.